# java generics T extends Simpletype?

Tags: java, generics

I'd like to write a method, that does return something of a PrimitiveType like float, integer, boolean and also String if possible. I'd like to use generics for it but i stuck and dont find a solution for it. I do need it for a Configparser. Ill use it to get different values from the Config.

Current it des look like this and i know that the switch does not work like this but you get an idea of what id like to do:

```
public class ConfigurationManager extends XmlReader {
    private final static String FILE_PATH = "config/config.cfg";
    private static Element xml;

    public ConfigurationManager() throws IOException {
        FileHandle handle = Gdx.files.internal(FILE_PATH);
        this.xml = this.parse(handle);
    }

    public Resolution getResolution() {
        Resolution r = new Resolution();
        r.height = xml.getFloat("height");
        r.width = xml.getFloat("width");
        return r;
    }

    public static <T> T getConfig(Class<T> type, String name) {
        if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
            return type.cast(xml.getInt(name));
        } else if (type.equals(Float.class)) {
            return type.cast(xml.getFloat(name));
        } else if (type.equals(Boolean.class)) {
            return type.cast(xml.getBoolean(name));
        } else if (type.equals(String.class)) {
            return type.cast(xml.get(name));
        }
        throw new AssertionError("Invalid type");
    }
}
```

Thanks alot

Comment: Just to clarify ... `String` types are reference types and not primitive types.  Moreover, primitive types cannot be used as the arguments to generic type parameters in Java.  Only reference types may be supplied as arguments ... you can always use the boxed forms of the primitive types if you need to.

Comment: Thanks I do know that but that's what I'd like to get so I tried to find a possible solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can do it with primitive types directly, but how about something like this:

```
public static <T> T getConfig(Class<T> type, String name) {
   if(type.equals(Integer.class)){
    return type.cast(xml.getInteger(name));
   } else if(type.equals(Float.class)){
    return type.cast(xml.getFloat(name));
   } else if(type.equals(Double.class)) {
    return type.cast(xml.getDouble(name));
   } else if(type.equals(String.class)) {
    return type.cast(xml.getString(name));
   } 
   throw new AssertionError("Invalid type");
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get the T to those types explicit? for example like T extends Float? Thats what i am looking for.

Comment: @BennX If you only want to support only numbers, you could something like: ```public static <T extends Number> T getConfig(Class<T> type, String name)```. But then you could not expect to pass a String class as argument.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Enum to avoid the branching logic and the explicit casting.

```
public enum TypeSelector {
    INTEGER() {
        @Override
        public Integer getValue(Elements xml, String name) {
            return xml.getInteger(name);
        }
    },

    DOUBLE() {
        @Override
        public Double getValue(Elements xml, String name) {
            return xml.getDouble(name);
        }
    };

     private static final Map<Class<?>, TypeSelector> SELECTORS = new HashMap<Class<?>, TypeSelector>() {
            {
                put(Integer.class, INTEGER);
                put(Double.class, DOUBLE);

            }
    };

    public static <T> TypeSelector getSelectorForType(Class<T> c) {
       TypeSelector selector = SELECTORS.get(c);
       if (selector == null) {
          throw new AssertionError("Invalid type");
       }
       return selector;
    }

    public abstract <T> T getValue(Elements xml, String name);
}
```